# Installing PHP on Linux from Windows

Tags: php, linux, windows, sqlite

My apologies if this answer already exists on here but I have not been able to find it.

I am trying to install an sqlite3 driver (verion 3.7.6.3) for php 5.2.14 on a Linux machine. Unfortunately this machine does not and cannot have internet access. I only have internet access on a fairly shutdown Windows machine (e.g. I can't use cmd) and I have the ability to transfer files to the Linux machine. Everything I have found so far has suggested running `apt-get install php5-sqlite` or another package manager from the Linux machine which obviously will not work with my present setup. The Linux machine also does not have a C compiler so I cannot compile the plug-in from source either.

I was wondering if anyone knew a way to manually download the correct package and install it or a reason why it cannot be done. rpm does exist on the Linux machine but I have not been able to download the correct .rpm package through the browser either.

The output of `uname -a` on the Linux machine is `Linux version 3.0.76-0.11-default` if that helps

Comment: why would you install php on a machine that has no internet ?

Comment: Might be used for some kind of script which is not a webpage, or a webpage in an internal network. (In one for my projects, for example, I had exactly this: PHP on a Raspberry Pi without internet, for accessing it through a direct LAN connection.)

Comment: Yeah it's for a webpage on an intranet